# Oracle SQL ROWNUM and NEXTVAL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sequence

I created a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE name_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

Then used it in my query:

```
select Name, ROWNUM, name_seq.NEXTVAL
from myTable;
```

Results into something like this:

```
+----+------+-------+
|Name|ROWNUM|NEXTVAL|
+----+------+-------+
|A   |     1|      1|     
|B   |     2|      2|
|C   |     3|      3| 
|D   |     4|      4|
|E   |     5|      5|
|F   |     6|      6|
|G   |     7|      7|
|H   |     8|      8|
|I   |     9|      9|
|J   |    10|     10|
+----+------+-------+
```

And from this, what I want the output to be is to use the next value of my sequence every after a number that I will declare. For example I'll use 4. The output should be like this:

In 1st run:

```
+----+------+-------+
|Name|ROWNUM|NEXTVAL|
+----+------+-------+
|A   |     1|      1|     
|B   |     2|      1|
|C   |     3|      1| 
|D   |     4|      1|
|E   |     5|      2|
|F   |     6|      2|
|G   |     7|      2|
|H   |     8|      2|
|I   |     9|      3|
|J   |    10|      3|
+----+------+-------+
```

Then in 2nd run:

```
+----+------+-------+
|Name|ROWNUM|NEXTVAL|
+----+------+-------+
|A   |     1|      4|     
|B   |     2|      4|
|C   |     3|      4| 
|D   |     4|      4|
|E   |     5|      5|
|F   |     6|      5|
|G   |     7|      5|
|H   |     8|      5|
|I   |     9|      6|
|J   |    10|      6|
+----+------+-------+
```

Comment: In the second case `NEXTVAL := TRUNC((ROWNUM-1)/4)+1`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No dude. I need to use the sequence that I created

Comment: OK, then use `NEXTVAL_COLUMN := TRUNC((YOUR_SEQ.NEXTVAL-1)/4+1`.

Comment: Your answers got the result that I wanted but the sequence current value will not be the same as the last value in the 3rd column

Comment: @BobJarvis dude I updated my question

Comment: If you want to group your data into buckets, you could use the NTILE analytic function. You don't need a sequence for that.

Comment: The table that I show is just the 2nd table and the 3rd column is used as a PK from my first table that's why I'm using sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE name_test_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_val     (p_num NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    IF p_num = 1 THEN
        RETURN name_test_seq.NEXTVAL;
    ELSE
        RETURN name_test_seq.CURRVAL;
    END IF;
END;
/

select rownum rown, get_next_val(MOD(rownum, :p_num))
  from dual
connect by rownum <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Select name,rownum,floor((name_seq.NEXTVAL-1)/4)+1 fl
from myTable
```

Comment: You don't do like that. This is fixed code, only work for a fixed sequence, and for this fixed case, you don't even need it, only need `floor(rownum - 1)...`

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I added a 2nd run output to make my question clearer

Answer (score 1):

Just substract the sequence last number.

```
with seq_cur_val as(
    select last_number seq_cv
    from user_sequences
    where sequence_name='NAME_SEQ'
)
select name, rownum,
    floor((name_seq.nextval-seq_cv)/4)+1
from myTable,seq_cur_val;
```